# Describing pronunciations: "You say it like" or "as"?

Tags: phrases

> How do you say *something* in English?
> You say it like/as/??? *something*.

So which word should I use here? Or maybe it will be more natural to say it some other way?

Comment: 'You pronounce it _flem_' is typical for a word.

Comment: What @EdwinAshworth said. You don't need any "noise words" when informing or correcting someone's pronunciation. Just *You say "**something**"*.

Comment: But note, "like" might be useful in giving a similarly-pronounced analogy: "*Bier* **sounds like** *beer*." Bottom line: there's no reason in any of the proposed constructions for "as." The whole "like vs as" issue comes down to whether there is a verb coming later ("I like to pronounce 'Paris' *as* the Parisians do"), and to how self-righteous you want to feel.